# update rows from joined tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to migrate some tables into an existing table, I need to perform the updates only where `DET_ATTACHMENT_ID` equals `DET_ATTACHMENT.ID`, here's the query I have so far.

```
UPDATE DET_ATTACHMENT
        SET attachment_type = 'LAB', -- being added by the query, to replace the table difference
            payer_criteria_id = (
            SELECT PAYER_CRITERIA_ID
            FROM DET_LAB_ATTACHMENT
            WHERE DET_LAB_ATTACHMENT.DET_ATTACHMENT_ID = DET_ATTACHMENT.ID)
        WHERE exists(
                SELECT DET_ATTACHMENT_ID
                FROM DET_ATTACHMENT
                    JOIN DET_LAB_ATTACHMENT ON (ID = DET_ATTACHMENT_ID)
                WHERE DET_ATTACHMENT_ID = DET_ATTACHMENT.ID
```

the problem with the existing query is that it's setting *every* row to have an `attachment_type` of "LAB", and nulling out the `payer_criteria_id` where it didn't match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are missing attachment_type = 'LAB' condition in the where exists clause

Comment: @Rajesh that doesn't exist until this update

Comment: @xenoterracide, you can this in the where exists clause                SELECT DET_ATTACHMENT_ID
                FROM DET_ATTACHMENT
                    JOIN DET_LAB_ATTACHMENT ON 
                 DET_ATTACHMENT_ID = DET_ATTACHMENT.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem **might be** that your `exists(...)` predicate always evaluates to `true`, thus making the `update` run for all rows of `det_attachment`. Try it this way:

```
UPDATE DET_ATTACHMENT X
SET X.attachment_type = 'LAB',
    X.payer_criteria_id = (
        SELECT C.PAYER_CRITERIA_ID
        FROM DET_LAB_ATTACHMENT C
        WHERE C.DET_ATTACHMENT_ID = X.ID
    )
WHERE
    exists(
        SELECT 1
        FROM DET_ATTACHMENT A
            JOIN DET_LAB_ATTACHMENT B
                ON B.DET_ATTACHMENT_ID = A.ID
            where B.det_attachment_id = X.id
    )
;
```